# Accessing Singleton values in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following singleton defined in Scala

```
package main

import javax.inject._

@Singleton
class Properties {
  val timeout = 120
}
```

how do I access it from other programs? I tried `main.Properties.timeout` but it throws a compilation error saying that a companion object was not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access it in the way, that you've mentioned: `main.Properties.timeout`, then use companion object instead:

```
class Properties {
   // ...
}
object Properties {
    val timeout = 120
    // ...
}
```

With `@Singleton` annotation, you have to inject that service somewhere, to be able to use it. So something like this:

```
import javax.inject._
import main.Properties

class SomeService @Inject() (props:Properties)() {
    println(props.timeout)
}
```

Here is documentation about DI for PlayFramework: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection - for the latest one (not 2.0), but it is a good start point.

Comment: Thanks, what would be the preferred method? I need to load the value from a properties file and have it accessible in all the application classes.

Comment: If values are in properties file, than maybe yet another way: through configuration? In newer versions of Play you have to inject play's configuration, so then you go for `@Inject`. If you want to keep it framework independent, just go for `@Inject`.